# PHP: cannot matching string "<br />

Tags: php

I'm having problems with string matching in PHP.

I've 2 html elements in my page, I've copy pasted here the content with Firebug

```
<div class="field-item odd">
     <div class="field-label-inline-first">
              Year:</div>
                    2009        </div>


<div class="field-item odd">
    <div class="field-label-inline-first">
                                  Synopsis:</div>
                                        &lt;br /&gt;
                            </div>
```

This php line works perfectly (the element with 2009 is detected)

```
<?php if ($items[0]['view'] == '2009') : echo "ok"; ?>
```

However I'm not able to match the string containing 
 element:

```
<?php if ($items[0]['view'] == '<br />') : echo "ok"; ?> //doesn't work
<?php if ($items[0]['view'] == '&lt;br /&gt;') : echo "ok"; ?> //again doesn't work
```

any tip ?

To give you some context:
The strings are produced by CKEditor, an editor I'm using in my Drupal back-end. When I leave empty this editor, the 
 tag is displayed on the string as plain text (because I set "plain text" as formatting option in the back-end)

Thanks

Comment: what's the relation between this code and these $items[0]['view'] variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try trimming it?

```
<?php if (trim($items[0]['view']) == '&lt;br /&gt;') : echo "ok"; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`&lt;br /&gt;` and `<br />` are not the same thing - from the looks of it, your `<` and `>` tags are in a different format than what you're searching for.

Either search for `&lt;br /&gt;` or use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) on your text.